# Is there a way to replicate android notification layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-notifications

I want to make some change in android notification layout. (I've checked all MO posts.) It seams that it is hard to do this. So I tried to include that layout in a custom layout as follow:

```
<include layout="@android:layout/notification_template_material_messaging"/>
```

But this gives

```
android.databinding.tool.processing.ScopedException: [databinding]
{"msg":"included value (@android:layout/notification_template_material_messaging) must start with @layout/."
```

error. Is there a way to use `notification_template_material_messaging`?

If not, in source code of `notification_template_material_messaging` there are some private and protected views like

- `<com.android.internal.widget.MessagingLayout`
- `<com.android.internal.widget.NotificationMaxHeightFrameLayout`

that I am not sure what is their appropriate replacement.